# Global start/end events for jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am reading through the documentation for jQuery file upload ([API options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)), and there don't appear to be events that signify "I am starting", and "I am done".  There are start and stop, but those are called for each file upload that is performed.

Does anyone know of an event that I am just not seeing, or have a suggestion for how to emulate the global start/stop operation?

Comment: [callback-options (fileuploadalways)](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options) and [always](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`progressall`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#progressall):

```
function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total, 10);
    if( progress === 1) {
        //done :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Using the add callback, I take action right before submit() is called.  I then used a sucessful progressall to process my 'done' action.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should be the `stop` callback function.

```
stop

Callback for uploads stop, equivalent to the global ajaxStop event (but for file upload requests only).

Example:

function (e) {
    console.log('Uploads finished');
}
```

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/990

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've got to a global 'start' is to handle the drop/change/paste events:

```
$('input[type="file"]').fileupload({
  // config here...
}).bind('fileuploaddrop fileuploadchange fileuploadpaste', function(e, data) {
  console.log('Global start');
});
```

This handler will fire once only; immediately after the user has initiated an upload, before processing the file queue (or any remote uploads) begin.

If you are doing *no client-side file validation*, [the answer by @Kamel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23949022/998793) works well for global 'end' ([as the documentation suggests](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#stop)).

*If you do validate client-side*, you may also need to deal with cases where an upload results in no ajax upload being triggered.  I did this by first recording the files that were uploaded, and then triggering 'end' once all had either been rejected client-side, or succeeded/failed/aborted following the ajax upload:

```
var selectedFiles = [];    
$('#fileUpload').fileupload({
    url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
    //url: '//does.not.exist/',
    dataType: 'json',
    singleFileUploads: true,
    // validate client-side: only allow '.png' files
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)png$/i,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
        });
    },
    processfail: function (e, data) {
        var currentFile = data.files[0];
        console.log(currentFile.name, 'cannot be uploaded');
        if (data.files.error && currentFile.error) {
            setFileDone(currentFile.name);
        }
    },
    always: function (e, data) {
        setFileDone(data.files[0].name);
    }
}).bind('fileuploaddrop fileuploadchange fileuploadpaste', function(e, data) {
    selectedFiles = data.files.map(function(f) { return f.name; });
    console.log('Global start');
});

var setFileDone = function(fName) {
    selectedFiles.pop(fName);
    if (!selectedFiles.length) {
        console.log('Global end');
    }
};
```

There is [a working demo of this on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kukexo/edit?html,js,output): the start and end are logged to the console as above.